# unknown variable 'pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid' when setting 50-server.cnf

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am modifying  /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf

When I add the following code, i get the error unknown variable 'pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid'

```
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

I am adding the mysql tag as well as it is not in the file, but I don't understand why this line is effecting the pid variable which seems to be defined in the mysql conf file.

Any ideas?

full contents of 50-server.cnf

```
[server]

[mysqld]
innodb-file-format=barracuda
innodb-file-per-table=1
innodb-large-prefix=1
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci

[mysql] 
default-character-set = utf8mb4

# * Basic Settings
#
user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                  = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
#port                   = 3306
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
#skip-external-locking

bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
query_cache_size        = 16M

log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

[embedded]

[mariadb]

[mariadb-10.3]
```

Comment: Can you annotate in your config where you tried putting those config lines?

Comment: Yes sure, I've added them in there. I wonder should mysql have a heading in there as well before modifying the file?

Comment: You canøt just add it in the miffle of another block ([mysqld]). It has to go before or after existing nlocks, that is just before {mysqld] or just before [embedded].

Comment: Thanks Soren, that explains it, I hadn't noticed the lack of a heading below! I'll try later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To formally put this as an answer, the square brackets denote sections of the config and you cut the `[mysqld]` section in half with your inserted `[mysql]` section.  This has the affect of putting the `pid-file` setting under `[mysql]` rather than `[mysqld]`.  Judging my the error, `[mysql]` does not have a a `pid-file` setting.

Either add your `[mysql]` settings at the top or bottom of the file and you should be set.  Alternatively, put them into a sibling file `50-server.cnf` called `51-client.cnf` so you can easily find them in the future (the number in the file name is load order and the name is arbitrary).